# Selector for only elements in containing div

Tags: jquery

I have several divs that are generated dynamically after a file is uploaded. Each file upload creates a div in this format:

```
<div id="uploadifive-fileupload-queue" class="uploadifive-queue">
    <div class="uploadifive-queue-item complete" id="uploadifive-fileupload-file-0">

        <div class="inputs">

            <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="0">
            <input type="text" name="alt-text">
            <input type="submit" name="image_data_submit" value="Submit" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Every item uploaded increments the id of the uploadifive-queue-item class to uploadifive-fileupload-file-0, uploadifive-fileupload-file-1, uploadifive-fileupload-file-2, etc.

I dynamically fill the hidden image_id from the response, so each hidden image_id field will have a different numerical value corresponding to the image_id I have stored in the database. This looks like:

```
'onUploadComplete'  : function(file, data) {    
     $('input[name=image_id]:last').val(data);
}
```

I am trying to fill out the alt-text input field with some text and then when clicking on the Submit button, it sends the command via ajax to the database where it updates the alt-text field in the database where the image_id matches.

The problem is I can't figure out how to make the Submit button only submit the image_id and alt-text that is in the same div container. Each div has a unique ID with an incremented number, but I'm not sure how to select that. How can I do it?

Basically, if the button in `uploadifive-fileupload-file-3` is submitted, I only want the image_id field from uploadifive-fileupload-file-3 to be submitted via ajax.

Here's how I have the jQuery ajax currently:

```
$("button[name=image_data_submit]").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: './update_image/',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                image_id: $("input[name=image_id]").val(), 
                alt_text: $("input[name=alt_texted]").val() 
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

I'd appreciate any help. Been stuck on this all day :/

Comment: Can't you simply replace `<div class="inputs">` (or another parent) to a `<form>`? They are block elements, and you can style them, etc.

Comment: You should be able to use `$("input[name=image_id]",$(this).parent()).val()` I think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How your code is right now it should be like this

EDITED :

You don't really need to know which div you're in.  You just need the input values by your submit button.  Also you you are selecting input with `"input[name=alt_texted]"` which is wrong.  It should be `input[name=alt-text]`

```
$("input[name=image_data_submit]").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: './update_image/',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            image_id: $(this).siblings("input[name=image_id]").val(), //<-- this = current element. then find sibling inputs
            alt_text: $(this).siblings("input[name=alt-text]").val() // <-- your alt_texted didn't match your html
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/utJKU/7/

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks so much! sorry about the html mixup, I tried to change up the code so it'd be easier to explain, but I guess my typo's didn't help either!

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting the values based on the location of the clicked element.

```
$("button[name=image_data_submit]").click(function(){
    var theDiv = $(this).closest(".uploadifive-queue");
    $.ajax({
        url: './update_image/',
        type: "POST",
        data: { 
            image_id: $("input[name=image_id]",theDiv).val(), 
            alt_text: $("input[name=alt_texted]",theDiv).val() 
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Interesting though... you are selecting a button, but your button is actually an input of type=submit. Does this click event work at all?

Answer (score 1):

if the button elements are added to the DOM dynamically you should delegate the click event for the buttons, try this:

```
$("body").on('click', 'input[name=image_data_submit]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: './update_image/',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
                image_id: $(this).parent().find("input[name=image_id]").val(), 
                alt_text: $(this).parent().find("input[name=alt_texted]").val() 
            },
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be much simpler to use an existing plugin?

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

A little code (see the `delegate` option at the docs):

```
$(function(){
    $('form').ajaxForm(...);
});
​
```

I changed a `div` to a `form` (you have to set its attributes):

```
<form class="uploadifive-queue-item complete" id="uploadifive-fileupload-file-0"
      action="./update_image/" method="POST">
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="hidden" name="image_id" value="0">
        <input type="text" name="alt-text">
        <input type="submit" name="image_data_submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```